# Почему слик не правильно добавляет класс slick-center?

Tags: jquery, slick.js

При переходе с 6 слайда на 1 слайдер дергается, а должен просто увеличить блок. Если листать назад, то все работает плавно и нет багов. Как можно это исправить?

```js
$('.sl').slick({
 centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: '0px',
  slidesToShow: 3,
});
```

```css
.sl {
 width: 500px;
}
.sl .sl-el {
 
}
h3{
   opacity: 0.8;
    transition: all 300ms ease;
  background: #3498db;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 2%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.slick-center h3{
     -moz-transform: scale(1.08);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.08);
    -o-transform: scale(1.08);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.08);
    color: #e67e22;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.08);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class="sl">
 <div class="sl-el">
  <h3>1</h3>
 </div>
 <div class="sl-el">
  <h3>2</h3>
 </div>
 <div class="sl-el">
  <h3>3</h3>
 </div>
 <div class="sl-el">
  <h3>4</h3>
 </div>
 <div class="sl-el">
  <h3>5</h3>
 </div>
 <div class="sl-el">
  <h3>6</h3>
 </div>
</div>
```